# Using while in for loop (PHP)

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following database:

```
|id|windspeed|
|1|3.6|
|2|4.2|
|3|4.1|
```

etc.

Now I want to output the last 5 values for windspeed, divided by a comma, but ending with the final value and not with a comma.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    print_r($aResult[$i][windspeed]);
    while ($i < 4) {
        print_r(", ");
    }
}
```

But this isn't working. Why not?

Comment: Easy, because inside the [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop, `$i` doesn't get incremented. You have made an infinite loop.

Comment: Take a look at the PHP `implode()` function.

Comment: `while` is also a *loop*, you probably mean `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a loop which goes on forever, $i never gets changed...

```
while ($i < 4) {
    print_r(", ");
}
```

maybe you meant this?

```
if ($i < 4) {
    print_r(", ");
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse. Sorry for bothering with this stupid mistake. It works now; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**`implode`**](https://www.php.net/implode).

If you wanted to get the last 5, use [**`array_reverse`**](https://www.php.net/array_reverse)

For example;

```
<?php

$a = array();
$a[1] = array("id" => 1, "windspeed" => 3.6);
$a[2] = array("id" => 2, "windspeed" => 4.2);
$a[3] = array("id" => 3, "windspeed" => 4.1);
$a[4] = array("id" => 4, "windspeed" => 5.1);
$a[5] = array("id" => 5, "windspeed" => 6.1);
$a[6] = array("id" => 6, "windspeed" => 7.1);
$a[7] = array("id" => 7, "windspeed" => 8.1);


$intIteration = 0;
$arrWindSpeeds = array();
foreach($a as $arrRecord) {
 
 $arrWindSpeeds[] = $arrRecord['windspeed'];
 
 if($intIteration >= 5) {
     break;
 }
 $intIteration++;
}

echo implode(", ", $arrWindSpeeds);
```

https://eval.in/200035

Comment: Thanks! For now I continued with the 'if' solution, but I'll try this one as well and will remember it for the next time!

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {           -- start the counter at 1, it will do exactly 5 loop not six which starts from 0
    print_r($aResult[$i][windspeed]);  -- you dont need print_r
    you can use 
    echo $aResult[$i][windspeed].", "; -- append a "," at the end of the var your getting 
    while ($i < 4) {                   -- you don't need the while loop either
        print_r(", ");
    }
}
```

use print_r if you want to see whats in an array.